# DDEML connection fails after large number of calls

Tags: delphi, openoffice.org, dde

Our Delphi 7 application communicates with the OpenOffice Calc DDE service, sOffice, using DDEML. It uses the service to read from a spreadsheet.

We've ran into a curious issue. After a large number of calls to 'DdeClientTransaction', the function returns a value of zero, indicating that it has failed. This failure is accompanied with the error 'DMLERR_NOTPROCESSED', which, according to http://www.opcdatahub.com/Docs/dhw-ax-windowsddeerrornumbers.html, means 'Receiving task was not interested in message'.

This is what we would expect to see if the DDE command was invalid. That is definitely not the case here. It happens after 16375 calls to 'DdeClientTransaction'. We can replicate this every time, over different spreadsheets.

To further confuse things, if we call DDEConnect after this failure, it returns a negative value. As far as we can tell, this is undocumented behavior. The function should return a positive handle or zero to indicate failure.

What's going on with the DDE connection and how do we fix it?

Comment: Is it feasible to do what you want using automation calls instead of DDE?

Comment: No. In this case we are adding support for OpenOffice Calc as an alternative to Excel for reading spreadsheets. We are already using DDE for the Excel communications so we won't put in a different type of implementation for OpenOffice when it should support DDE just fine.

Comment: Then probably best to try and isolate whether it's OO's DDE support that's causing the problem or Delphi's.  Delphi's DDE support never had a reputation for being 100% robust and the chances of getting anything fixed in it now are probably about zero.

Comment: Since the exact same behavior functions fine when using the Excel DDE service it must be something to do with OpenOffice's support.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't be so sure that if it works with Excel, it must be an OO problem, but ymmv.